# extract FASTA sequence using sequence ID

Tags: perl, design-patterns, matching

I have two files:
File 1:

```
84C2_Locus_14_Transcript_1/3_Confidence_0.571_Length_1244
AAACTAGTCAATAGAGAAAATCCAAAGTGGATGAAATTGAAGTGATTGTATGGCACAAGT...so on

>84C2_Locus_14_Transcript_2/3_Confidence_0.857_Length_1961
AAACTAGTCAATAGAGAAAATCCAAAGTGGATGAAATTGAAGTGATTGTATGGCACAAGT...so on

>84C2|Locus_15_Transcript_1/9_Confidence_0.190_Length_757
ATTTGCTCGGAAAAACACTTCTCGTGGAACTTGTTAGCGCTGAGCTTGATCCCAAGACGA.....so on

>84C2_Locus_15_Transcript_5/9_Confidence_0.333_Length_1841
ATTTGCTCGGAAAAACACTTCTCGTGGAACTTGTTAGCGCTGAGCTTGATCCCAAGACGA....so on
```

File2: only the sequence IDS

```
84C2_Locus_14_Transcript_1/3_Confidence_0.571_Length_1244
84C2_Locus_14_Transcript_2/3_Confidence_0.857_Length_1961
84C2_Locus_14_Transcript_3/3_Confidence_0.571_Length_1248
84C2_Locus_15_Transcript_1/9_Confidence_0.190_Length_757
```

...........so many.

my output file should be contain the sequence associated with header. i.e. matching the sequence id file header portion with original fasta sequence file and those sequences header match the fasta sequence header store in another output file containing header with sequence.Just like this:

Original output file should like this:

```
>84C2_Locus_15_Transcript_5/9_Confidence_0.333_Length_1841
ATTTGCTCGGAAAAACACTTCTCGTGGAACTTGTTAGCGCTGAGCTTGATCCCAAGACGA......so on
```

Please suggest me the way in perl which is applicable for my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you provide your code? What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into? Also, could yo reduce the contents of the files you posted to the portions relevant to the question?

Comment: The output file which i was getting only the header portion of sequence not the sequence and header as in my File 1.Thanks

Comment: Actually i want in my output file the fuul header portion associated with sequence. According to sequence id file it checks the sequence header portion and give the output file header associated with full sequence.

Comment: Your required output looks the same as your first input file. What am I missing?

Comment: absolutely correct Borodin. The final output file contain the sequences which actually match the header pattern according to my sequence id files.

Comment: Ah, so you want to extract the blocks named in the sequence ID file?

Comment: my sequence id file  i.e file 2 containing the header match the header line of sequence file i.e. file 1 and when the header match and the final output file contain the sequence along with header like the input sequence file 1

Comment: I have two input file one is sequence file and another one is sequence id file contain only the header part of the main sequence file. The program is actually doing what a simple pattern matching program. The user give two input files and according to the second input file i.e. sequence id file match the header portion of sequence file and final output file contain the sequence along with header which actually match the header part of sequence id file. That is extract the sequence from 1st sequence file according the header part of sequence id file i.e. file 2.

Comment: kindly give me the suggestion for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** New code, I didn't understand your question the first time. This script reads both files, stores all IDs in a hash and then goes through all sequences in the first file. Only those sequences whose IDs are in the second file get written into the output file. Note that the output is written with `|` as separator like in the first file, not `_` like the IDs in the second file. The missing `>` in the beginning of the first file is also reproduced correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

# Check command line arguments
unless ($#ARGV == 1 && -e $ARGV[0] && -e $ARGV[1]) {
        print STDERR "Usage: split-fasta.pl DATA IDS\n";
        exit 1;
}

my (%ids, $id);

# Read sequence IDs
open(IDS, "<$ARGV[1]") or die "Can't open IDs file: $1";

while (<IDS>) {
        $ids{$_} = 1;
}

close(IDS);


# Read sequence data and write results to output.fasta
open(DATA,    "<$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open sequences file: $1";
open(OUTFILE, ">>output.fasta") or die "Can't open output file: $1";

while (<DATA>) {
        my $line = $_;


        if ($line =~ /^>?(\w+\|.+\n)/) {
                $id = $1;
                $id =~ tr/|/_/;
        }

        print OUTFILE $line if defined $ids{$id};
}

close(DATA);
close(OUTFILE);
```

<s>So, you basically want to split file 1 into multiple files that each only contain one sequence? Maybe this ugly (maybe close each filehandle and not only the last one ...) piece of Perl will help you out.</s>

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

while (<>) {
        my $line = $_;

        if ($line =~ />?([0-9]+|\w+)\//) {
                my $file_name = $1;
                open(OUTFILE, ">>$file_name");
        }

        print OUTFILE $line;
}

close(OUTFILE);
```

**Edit:** In case you want to feed in IDs from the second file, just add another `if` that matches the ID with the headers from the first file. This should work as long as both files are in the same order since the input is immediately discarded upon writing and can't be searched anymore.

Comment: Thanks wheee. My requirement is that produce a single output file which containing the sequences along with header portion that match with the header of sequence id file i.e. file 2.

Comment: Thanks wheee i think this code is helpful for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Oh, and can you click 'accept' for my answer, please? Thank you.

Comment: Wheee as per your suggestion i am writing your code with slight modification. But the output file show only the header portion not the sequence. Kindly check my code and suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $list = $ARGV[0] || 'accessionids.txt';
my $data = $ARGV[1] || 'fasta.txt';
my $outs = $ARGV[2] || 'SQ.fas';
my (%ids, $id);
open (LIST,$list) or die "Cannot open file $list: $!\n";
while (<LIST>) {
      $ids{$_} = 1;
    }
close LIST;
open (IN, $data) or die "Cannot open file $data: $!\n";;
while (<IN>) {
 my $line = $_;
 if ($line =~ /^>?(\w+\|.+\n)/) {
    $id = $1;
    $id =~ tr/|/_/;
       }
       }
       close IN;
       open (OUT, ">$outs") or die "Cannot create file $outs: $!\n";
foreach my $id (@list) {
    print OUT ">$id\n";
}
close OUT;

Comment: There's two problems:1) You never read the sequences, only the IDs from the header in the FASTA file. 2) The `@list` array in the last `foreach` loop is never initialized. Consider writing both the sequences and the headers in same loop you use for reading the FASTA file.

Comment: Thanks Whee as you said I am already done  initialize @list  for foreach loop but the output file getting blank ni information in it. Kindly verify my code once again. Thanks for your support.

Comment: my $list = $ARGV[0] || 'accessionids.txt';
my $data = $ARGV[1] || 'fasta.txt';
my $outs = $ARGV[2] || 'SQ.fas';
my (%ids, $id);
my @list = ();
open(IDS, $list)or die "Cannot open file $list: $!\n";
while (<IDS>) {
        $ids{$_} = 1;
}

close(IDS);

open (IN, $data) or die "Cannot open file $data: $!\n";;
while (<IN>) {
 my $line = $_;
 if ($line =~ /^>?(\w+\|.+\n)/) {
    $id = $1;
    $id =~ tr/|/_/;
       }
       }
       close IN;
       open (OUT, ">$outs") or die "Cannot create file $outs: $!\n";
foreach my $id (@list) {
    print OUT ">$id\n";
}
close OUT;

Comment: I need my output file contain both the header portion along with sequence itself. Those sequences whose header portion match with the header portion of sequence id file i.e. file 2.

Comment: There is still nothing inside `@list`, since you never put anything in it. All you have is one single ID in `$id`. The output is empty because you redefine `$id` as a new variable in the `foreach` loop (`my $id`). The previous value is overwritten. You have to do something with the lines that aren't headers as well. Look at the second `while` loop in my code again. Also, could you put your new code into your question and just tell us about the updates in the comments? That way it would be properly formatted. It's very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: ok. i am giving here one code which i had modified with your code. just check my code and suggest me where put your code with my code.

Comment: my $list = $ARGV[0] || 'accessionids.txt';
my $data = $ARGV[1] || 'fasta.txt';
my $outs = $ARGV[2] || 'SQ.fas';
my (%ids, $id);
my @list = ();
open(IDS, $list)or die "Cannot open file $list: $!\n";
while (<IDS>) {
        $ids{$_} = 1;
}
close(IDS);
open (IN, $data) or die "Cannot open file $data: $!\n";;
while (<IN>) {
 my $line = $_;
 if ($line =~ /^>?(\w+\|.+\n)/) {
    $id = $1;
    $id =~ tr/|/_/;
       }
       }
       close IN;
       open (OUT, ">$outs") or die "Cannot create file $outs: $!\n";
foreach my $id (@list) {
    print OUT ">$id\n";
}
close OUT;

Comment: This is the same code as before, I think you copied the wrong one. But please, edit your original question post and add the code there. These small comment fields without formatting are terrible to read.

Comment: ok. if possible kindly give me your email id so i mailed you in details..

Comment: I'm sorry but I'd rather not post my email address here. Just read my code again and try to understand what each part does and why it is important, especially the parts where the hash `%ids` is used. Then head over to your code and check which parts are still missing from it. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: ok. thanks wheee for your suggestion